# Assigning hash value through iteration ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, iteration

I'm having a hash with all the value is blank.

> hash_obj =  {:username => '', :name => '', :phone => ''}

get_row_datas is getting data which is an array.

> [[john1, john2, 0123], [john3, john4, 345]]

I'm trying to assign those value into the hash_obj, so that it will become

> hash_array = {:username => 'john1', :name => 'john2', :phone =>
>   '0123'}, {:username => 'john3', :name => 'john4', :phone => '345'}

```
def get_hash_array
  first_row_data = get_first_row
  hash_obj = Hash.new
  first_row_data.each do |column|
    hash_obj[column.to_sym] = ''
  end

  hash_array = Hash.new

  row_datas = get_row_datas
  row_datas.each_with_index do |row, row_count|
    puts "Rows datas #{row} and row count is #{row_count}"
    hash_obj.each_with_index do |attribute, attribute_count|
      hash_obj[attribute] = row[attribute_count] //problem occurs
      puts "This is attribute #{attribute} and count #{attribute_count}"
      puts "#{row[attribute_count]}"
    end
  end

  hash_obj
end
```

I want to ask how to assign value because you can see my code, there will be an error.
RuntimeError: can't add a new key into hash during iteration

Comment: And what is your question ?

Comment: Your code is very dirty looking in this context. take another approach or mine one to get the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below technique also :

```
hash_obj = {:username => '', :name => '', :phone => ''}
val = [[:john1, :john2, 0123], [:john3,:john4, 345]]

val.map{|i| Hash[hash_obj.keys.zip(i)]}
# => [{:username=>:john1, :name=>:john2, :phone=>83},
#     {:username=>:john3, :name=>:john4, :phone=>345}]
```

> but I did that with map! but not map, do you know what cause that?

The cause is as follows :

> **map { |item| block } → new_ary**: *Creates a new array containing the values returned by the block.*

```
hash_obj = {:username => '', :name => '', :phone => ''}
val = [[:john1, :john2, 0123], [:john3,:john4, 345]]
new_hash = val.map{|i| Hash[hash_obj.keys.zip(i)]}
val
# => [[:john1, :john2, 83], [:john3, :john4, 345]]
```

> **map! {|item| block } → ary**: *Invokes the given block once for each element of self, replacing the element with the value returned by the block*

```
hash_obj = {:username => '', :name => '', :phone => ''}
val = [[:john1, :john2, 0123], [:john3,:john4, 345]]
new_hash = val.map!{|i| Hash[hash_obj.keys.zip(i)]}
val
# => [{:username=>:john1, :name=>:john2, :phone=>83},
#     {:username=>:john3, :name=>:john4, :phone=>345}]
```

Comment: hi thanks ! but I did that with map! but not map, do you know what cause that?

Comment: @Nich see my post I answered your question.. ;)

Comment: cool, that is a detail answer :)